# .Net Core different cultures per view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a scenario where I want to support multi-language only for few views and not for the others.
Meaning, that if a user navigates to:
/en/home or /fr/home user should get a translated view. However, if a user navigates to /en/locations or /fr/locations user should get 404 and locations view should only be available on /locations.

What I tried is:

```
app.UseWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.Contains("locations", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), 
        appBuilder =>
        {
            app.UseRequestLocalization(GetMultiLangOptions());
        });
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{culture=tr}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "type2",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

But that didn't achieve what I need. Any way I can define a route template per controller?

Comment: is `/locations/` a special case ?

Comment: Actually, it is not just /locations, I have many views that I want to support multi-lang and many that shouldn't

Comment: _May be not the best solution_. Remove the `{culture}` parameter from the route mapping in startup, and instead use it in controllers that requires culture, and just avoid it where you don't need it.